# sendGrid Mailing implementaion in symfony 2 application using tystr/sendgrid bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sendgrid, email

1)   I have followed steps from this link https://packagist.org/packages/tystr/sendgrid-bundle

2)    I have already created sendGrid account and got api key.

3)    in config.yml i added

```
tystr_sendgrid:
username: username
password: password
```

4)    and written this code in mailing fuction of command:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Periodic Report')
        ->setFrom('abc@gmail.com')
        ->setTo($userEmail)
        ->setBody(
        $this->getContainer()->get('templating')->render(
                'aaaaa:layouts:mailReportSend.txt.twig',   
array('data'=> $data)
        )
);
$sendgrid = $this->getContainer()->get('tystr_sendgrid.sendgrid');
$sendgrid->send($message);
```

This is giving me an error that Attempted to call an undefined method named "send" of class "SendGrid".

Extra words: currently i'm using mailgun without any issue, and now wish to use sendGrid of which i have not enough idea, is there any other bundle which will be used to complete this sendGrid with symfony 2 integration.